# Algorithm for finding the shortest path between geocoordinates

Tags: algorithm, a-star

AStar works on the basis of **straight** lines, AFAIK.

In my case, we have geocoordinates and I can get the straight line distance between the waypoints. But I am wondering how approximate will that be? The actual distance "by road", which actually matters can be different.

Example.
Assuming A and B are on the same plane, and will be equidistant from the goal point, if we consider a straight line between A and the goal point and, B and the goal point.

The distance "by road" between A and the goal point may be greater or lesser than B. But because the AStar works on the basis of straight lines, it will return both the routes as the shortest.

Is that correct?

If yes, then which algo should be considered , if we want the results on the basis of actual distance in Km/m?

If no, then what's the point that I am missing?

Comment: "AStar works on the basis of straight lines, AFAIK" — No, of course not. It works with any graph (with positive edge distances, etc). You just need to set up the distances between vertices to what you want: in this case, the road distances.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks but wikipedia says `Thus, for an application like routing, h(x) might represent the straight-line distance to the goal, since that is physically the smallest possible distance between any two points or nodes.` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Description

Comment: "Might" means that it's not the only possibility. Also, h(x) is the "heuristic", not the actual distance d(x,y). You can of course use straight-line distance as your heuristic for your problem since straight-line distance is never more than the actual road distance. Or you can use some other admissible heuristic. That's what the Wikipedia article is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, since you asked me to post an answer….

Before you understand A*, you must first understand [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Given a graph (a set of nodes, and edges between nodes) and the (positive) "distance" of each edge (e.g. the road distance), Dijkstra's algorithm gives the shortest distance between a certain source node and each destination node. For instance, in your graph, the nodes may be road-intersections, the edges may be the roads, and the weight/distance you put on an edge may be the length of that road, or the time it takes to traverse it, or whatever.

Please understand: Dijkstra's algorithm always gives the correct distance according to the weights you have put on the edges. In fact, the graph need not even be embeddable in a plane, i.e., there may be no notion of "straight line distance" in the first place. It can be any arbitrary graph.

Now, A* can be thought of as a particular heuristic to speed up Dijkstra's algorithm. You can think of it as using a heuristic to decide the order in which to consider nodes in the graph.

Formally: you have a graph G, two nodes s and t in it, and you want to find the distance d(s,t) between s and t. (The distance is according to the graph, e.g. according to road distance in your example.) To find d(s,t), in A* you use a heuristic function h(x) which satisfies h(x) ≤ d(x,t). For *instance* (just one possibility), you can choose h(x) to be the straight line distance from x to t. The better h(x) is as an estimate of d(x,t), the faster the A* algorithm will run, but the choice of h affects only the speed, not the answer: it will always give the shortest distance according to d, not h.

So to find the road distance s to t, just set d(u,v) to be the road distance for every pair of nodes u and v with a road between them, run A*, and you'll find the d(s,t) you want.

Comment: Very grateful to you. :hattip: Perhaps I should now understand and implement Dijkstra's algo, and later on think of adding the heuristic function.

Comment: Hey, one more question, now since we are talking of graphs, does Dijkstra's algo handle cycles?

Comment: @Anisha: Yes, it works fine if the graph has cycles. (Assuming again that all edge distances are positive, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, the distances will be positive (at least in my case, they are in km, so they can't be negative). Meanwhile I found a very easy explanation of Dijkstra's algo here: http://optlab-server.sce.carleton.ca/POAnimations2007/DijkstrasAlgo.html

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I have a question related to A* algorithm. does it always give the shortest path between the two points? Because, I have a 2D grid with horizontal and vertical obstacles, and the obstacles can be really dense and mazy. Now, for most part of the grid, the path found is shortest, but sometimes,  see a bit of clumsiness in the final path. i.e. it is not shortest? What can be the possible reasons for that? Is A* not always supposed to give the shortest path?

Comment: @Kraken: A* always gives the shortest path if implemented correctly. This means using an admissible heuristic, i.e. with a heuristic function h(x) satisfying h(x) ≤ d(x,t).

Answer (score 3):

By default, [A-star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) operates on a graph with edges having non-negative weights.  There is no constraint that the edges have to be straight lines.  The thing that makes A-star different, than say [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), is that it uses a heuristic in which nodes of the graph to search first.  This heuristic is typically chosen to be Euclidean distance between nodes in the case of a graph embedded in Euclidean space, though there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can model the situation with a weighted graph, where vertices are the points you consider, and the edges between them have the weights equal to the road distances between corresponding points. Then you can use, for example, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)  to find the shortest distance between points.

For example, if you have points A and B on a plane, and the road distance between them is equal to C, then in graph you will have vertices [A] and [B] and an edge of length C between them:

```
[A]---C---[B]
```

Comment: Thanks Grigor, but is it true that Astar works on the basis of straight lines?

Comment: As you can see in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm,  A* is equivalent to running Dijkstra's algorithm with the reduced cost d'(x,y): = d(x,y) − h(x) + h(y). You just need to give appropriate weights to the edges. And, yes, it works with straight-line distances, i.e. physically the smallest possible distances between any two points or nodes. h(x) in the formulas is the straight-line distance from startpoint to point x.

Comment: "it works with straight-line distances" only if you choose the heuristic h(x) to be the straight-line distance, but you can also choose other heuristics. And *even* if you choose h(x) to be the straight-line distance, the distance given by A* will be the actual distance in the graph (road distance or whatever you want), not the straight-line distance. This may not be clear to the OP yet.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR  You said: _"And even if you choose h(x) to be the straight-line distance, the distance given by A* will be the actual distance in the graph (road distance or whatever you want), not the straight-line distance. "_ Can you bother to give a detailed explanation on this statement as a separate "answer", please?